# Java graphics not working in timer

Tags: java, animation, graphics, timer, paint

I am programming a tiny game in java. For that I want to print a dialog-text-box with some text in it to talk to people inside the game.

```
    public static void printConBox(Graphics g, String firstLine, String secondLine, String thirdLine, String fourthLine){
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 600, 180);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(i <= firstLine.length() - 1){
                char c = firstLine.charAt(i);
                i++;
                String s = "" + c;
                System.out.print(s);
                g.drawString(s, xdif, y + 25);
                xdif += 15;
            }else{
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }

    }, 0, 100);}
```

Don't worry about the graphics, this is working because the programm is painting the white Text-Box. But the letters in the String 'firstLine' arent there. In run this should be an animation for the text!

I think this has to do with der Timer! But the printing in the output-Console is working perfectly! I also try it with Thread.sleep in a for-loop, but still not working...

Any ideas?...

PS.: I have use paintComponent and that, so the graphics is working believe me ;)

Comment: A Graphics object is only valid for the duration of the paint method which receives it.  You cannot “save” it for later use in a delayed timer task.  Your timer must alter the relevant data and then tell the component to repaint (part of) itself.  Note that it is good idea to use javax.swing.Timer rather than java.util.Timer when working with AWT and Swing, due to threading issues.

Comment: Ok Thanks i'll try it... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
    if(Conversation.i <= firstLine.length() - 1){
        char c = firstLine.charAt(Conversation.i);
        Conversation.i++;
        String s = "" + c;
        System.out.print(s);
        g.drawString(s, Conversation.xdif, Conversation.y + 25);
        Conversation.xdif += 15;
        Conversation.timer.restart();
    }else{
        Conversation.timer.stop();
    }
}
```

But how do I get the Graphics in der actionPerformed, the Timer works with?
By the way the System.out is working angain! Nice... ;)

Comment: I solved it :) Special thanks to VGR, that was a big help. If someone want too see the solution pls add a comment here...